# Accept Microsoft's PsTools T.O.S. in bat/cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How to accept terms of service in either cmd or bat?
 I've tried

```
cmd.exe /c echo "Y" | terms.exe
```

and

```
cmd.exe /c echo "A" terms.exe
```

I'm sure I'm just making a rookie error if its possible. My goal is to auto accept the T.O.S. of Microsoft's PsTools.

Comment: Check here: http://forum.sysinternals.com/eula-prompt-when-running-pstools_topic8783.html . Add the `-accepteula` parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `/accepteula` flag to automatically accept the TOS.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to code a flag for this in the application. There is no universal way to do this.

After setting a flag such as Y, you will have to call it with the flag in command line argument.

If you are looking for specific tools, read more about silent install of those tools.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to thank you for the help. Very appreciated.